# nodemanager is not starting while upgrading to hadoop 2 from hadoop classic

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have one master one worker cluster. I am upgrading to **YARN** from Hadoop classic. **resourcemanager** and **historyserver** successfully started, but **nodemanager** is not starting it is giving error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${nodemanager.resource.memory-mb}"

I have kept same `yarn-site.xml.template` in both server.

> I have replaced `${nodemanager.resource.memory-mb}` to **8192**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>__RM_IP__</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
   <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8030</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
   <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8031</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
   <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
   <value>${nodemanager.resource.memory-mb}</value>
  </property>
</configuration></br>
```

Comment: is `yarn-site.xml.template` file renamed to `yarn-site.xml`?

Comment: also `<value>${nodemanager.resource.memory-mb}</value>` should be `<value>${yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb}</value>`

Comment: @BigDataLearner I have both `yarn-site.xml.template` and  `yarn-site.xml` in my servers and I am updating only in `yarn-site.xml.template`   And for second comment I am providing value **8192** not using placeholder

Comment: from error it seems, it is still reading the variable. do you have same property define in `yarn-default.xml` config?
Just remove the property from `yarn-site.xml` as [default is `8192mb`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) - so there is no need to set in `yarn-site.xml`.

Comment: We don't have `yarn-default.xml` but when I provide property for `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` , value **8192** `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` , value **8**  and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.io-spindles` value **2.0**. In `yarn-site.xml` Nodemanager got started